# Retrieving Max value(select query) from MySQL using PHPSECLIB

Tags: mysql, phpseclib

I am able to connect to remote server and its MySQL tables successfully using phpseclib. I am unable to fetch a max value of a column and try to insert into another table. The output I am getting is `max(test_id) 1`. Not sure where i might be going wrong?

```
$value = $ssh->exec("mysql -h localhost -u root -pXXXX DBname -e \"SELECT max(test_id) FROM cpu_util_all;\"");

echo "$value"; - output : max(test_id) 1

echo $ssh->exec("mysql -h localhost -u root -pXXXX DBname -e \"INSERT INTO  test_execution (test_id) values ('$value');\"");
```

Comment: That actually looks correct because the query would return a tabular output with the column name at the top. Since you didn't use an alias, `max(test_id)` would be the column name. If you query as SELECT max(test_id) AS an_alias...` your output would be an_alias.  Add `--skip-column-names` to get only the value back.  I assume `1` is the max value in that column. If you expect linebreaks and are writing this output to HTML in the browser, use `nl2br($value)`

Comment: For the INSERT, I'm less certain of what output it would produce in that context.